# Parse text with Applscripts

Tags: applescript

I could use some help writing an Applescript to parse some text from a .txt file and output to a separate .txt file. I need a script to 1) identify a section (delisted by “»=“), 2) identify if a specific set of characters exists in a section, “[*]”, 3) print section header with all sections that contain specific set of characters, 4) repeat to end of file. Basically, these are notes with action items, and I want to extract the notes that contain open action items.

Input text structure from notes.txt is as follows:

```
»===============================

<Date> 2016-09-19
<Topic> The topic of the day
<Attendees> Mario, Luigi

»1) Where to go from here
- Someone said this
    [*] Mario: schedule this meeting
- And who wants to do that other thing?

»2) And on to the next thing

»3) So on and so forth [*] Luigi can order the pizza
»===============================

<Date> 2016-09-18
<Topic> The topic of the yesterday
<Attendees> Zelda, Wario, Snoop Dog

»1) Where we went from there
- Who said this
    [x] Mario: scheduled this meeting yesterday
- And who wants to do that other thing?

»2) And on to the next thing again

»3) So on and so forth * Luigi can order the sausages
»===============================
```

Output text to actionItems.txt should be as follows:

```
»===============================

<Date> 2016-09-19
<Topic> The topic of the day
<Attendees> Mario, Luigi

»1) Where to go from here
- Someone said this
    [*] Mario: schedule this meeting
- And who wants to do that other thing?

»3) So on and so forth [*] Luigi can order the pizza
»===============================
```

Maybe I can get a little help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing text file is quite easy with Applescript :

Read :

```
set myFile to choose file "Select your txt file" -- ask user to select txt file
set myText to (read myFile) as string -- content the text file is in variable myText
```

Write content of text variable newText into file 'action items.txt' on your desktop :

```
set newFile to ((path to desktop) as string) & "actionItems.txt"
try
    open for access file newFile with write permission
    write (newText & return) to file newFile starting at eof
    close access file newFile
on error
try
    close access file newFile
end try
end try
```

In between, you must split your text using the powerful 'item text delimiters'. You must first define the delimiters like :

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"»=", "¬ª="}
```

(during my test, I found that your "»=" should be, in fact set as "¬ª=" !!)

Then you can access to each text item (the part of text between 2 delimiters) through a repeat loop :

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"»=", "¬ª="}
set myNotes to text items of myText
set newText to ""
repeat with I from 1 to (count of myNotes) --loop through each item
    -- do what ever you need with 'item I of myNotes'
    set Newtext to "this is my test" -- assign new text to be written
end repeat
```

You will need to adjust your tests in the loop: for instance if your text starts with a space, then, 1st item will not be your expected header, but a space !

Last thing : to test if a text variable contains something, use the 'contains' word :

```
Set A to "This is my text sample"
if A contains "is my" then 
    -- A contains 'is my'
else
    -- A do not contains 'is my'
end if
```

Good luck !